# JQM Calendar is not refreshing after Add Event or Delete Event

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, calendar

I am using following calendar plugin in my phonegap application https://github.com/JWGmeligMeyling/jqm-calendar for calendar events

I my application I allowed the user to add event the event and the added event will be saved to Database for feature use and also allow the user to delete the event from the server with the help of services

If the user add or delete the event means I will reload my array and refresh the calendar.

If I reload the the array and refresh the calendar means it is not refreshing until I click the next or previous button

I am using following line to refresh my calendar in **pageshow**

Refresh code : **$("#calendar").trigger('refresh');**

To  illustrate the issue clearly I have page show attached my code  below

```
$.mobile.document.on( "pagebeforeshow", "#view-calendar", function() {

if(vcal){
alert("pgshow");
$("#calendar").trigger('refresh');
}
$('#addcal').on( "tap", function( event ) {
eventflag=false;
$.mobile.changePage("#add-calendar");
});
$.mobile.loading( 'show');

var eventsss;
var uid= localStorage.getItem('uid');

var ss='data={"uid":"'+uid+'"}';

$.ajax({
url:"http://trendy.twomini.com/pinapp/index.php/version/listevent",
type:'POST',
data:ss,
cache: true,
dataType: 'text',
crossDomain: true,
ContentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
error: function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown) {
var res=JSON.stringify(XMLHttpRequest);
var datareg = JSON.parse(res);
console.log(datareg);
$("#calendar").jqmCalendar();
},
success: function (data) {
$.mobile.loading( 'hide');
var data=eval('('+data+')');
eventnamearr=[];


var startdate;
var enddate;
$.each(data.msg, function(i,item){

var str =item.start_date;
var str1 =item.end_date;
var res = str.split(" ");
var res1 = str1.split(" ");

var id=item.id;


startdate=res[3]+'-'+convertMonthNameToNumber(res[1])+'-'+res[2]+' '+res[4];
enddate=res1[3]+'-'+convertMonthNameToNumber(res1[1])+'-'+res1[2]+' '+res1[4];


eventsss={"summary":item.event_name,"begin":new Date(startdate),"end":new Date(enddate),"id":item.id,"location":item.location};
eventnamearr.push(eventsss);





});
$("#calendar").jqmCalendar({
events : eventnamearr, // Point to the events array now
months : ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
days : ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa"],
startOfWeek : 0
});


}

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pagebeforeshow only happens when redirecting through JQM. You should add the refresh tied to your event that modifies calendar content.

Answer (score 0):

You're initialising the calendar multiple times, currently the settings are not updated using the way above. You should initialise the calendar once, pointing to an array of events and then push to that array:

```
// Create an array that will contain the events
var eventsArray = [];

// Dynamically add events to the array (this can be done later on as well)
eventsArray.push({ "summary" : "Test event", "begin" : new Date(), "end" : new Date() }); 

// Initialize the calendar
$("#calendar").jqmCalendar({
   events : eventsArray, // Point to the events array now
   months : ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
   days : ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa"],
   startOfWeek : 0
}); 

// Add another event
eventsArray.push({ "summary" : "Test event", "begin" : new Date(), "end" : new Date() }); 

// Trigger refresh
$('#calendar').trigger('refresh');
```

Source: the issue is similar to https://github.com/JWGmeligMeyling/jqm-calendar/issues/12